# What is the naming convention for produceGroupName?

Tags: rocketmq

If I set the produceGroupName like '192.168.1.1:9889-1234-uuid',It will cause the exception:**MQClientException The producer service state not OK, START_FAILED.** If I only set the produceGroupName like uuid,it is ok.So I curious about the naming convention for produceGroupName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention of `producerGroupName` allows only `^[%|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$`, which means that the prefix of the name you provided, `192.168.1.1:9889-1234-uuid`, contains the illegal character `.` That would lead to the exception.